# HBase search in json fields

Tags: json, hadoop, indexing, hbase

Is there any way for fast search in json that stored in HBase table? For example, i have table with some json strings saved in same *columnFamily:column*:

```
1      {"name":"John McClane","hat_color":"green"}
2      {"name":"Rocky Balboa","hat_color":"red"}
.......
9999   {"name":"Super Man","hat_color":"green"}
.......
```

I need to find all row ids of everyone, who have **green** hat.

Assume, table is too large for using simple MapReduce job, which will parse jsons

Maybe there is a way for indexing json fields?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using scan operation with [hbase value filter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ValueFilter.html) with
operator = `CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL` 
comparator = `RegexStringComparator` 
and the regex string is
`"hat_color":"green"}$`

I don't know the performance comparation against a mapreduce job, but for a simple retrieval operations that should do

note: also look at [hbase single column value filter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html)